# Dynamic created function return incorrect value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback

I am trying to create dynamic function in loops. However, the dynamic function return unexpected value. Here is my code.

```js
var obj = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B'
}

for(var key in obj) {
    var value =  obj[key];
    obj['get'+key] = function() {
    return value;
  }
}

alert(obj.geta());
```

I am expecting `geta()` to return `A` and `getb()` to return `B`. However, both of them return `B`. I have tried to use the debug mode in Chrome which find out that `value` is not reset in each iteration. Shouldn't the variable in the loop different in each iteration?

What am I doing wrong? Am I having something miss understanding?

Comment: Use `let` to declare value variable i.e. `let value = obj[key]`or closure

Comment: @Joshua, it is working for you ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai It works but not for me. I cannot use ECMAScript 6 because of browser compatibility. I found another solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `let` keyword in order to declare  variable visible only in your `block`.

Read more about [let keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

```js
var obj = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B'
}

for(var key in obj) {
    let value =  obj[key];
    obj['get'+key] = function() {
    return value;
  }
}

alert(obj.geta());
```

Another method is to use `.bind()` method which creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value.

```js
var obj = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B'
}

for(var key in obj) {
    var value =  obj[key];
    obj['get'+key] = (function(val) {
    return val;
  }).bind(this,value);
}

alert(obj.geta());
```

Read more about [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).